# ServiceStack.Redis ModelConfig Id error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redis, servicestack

I have a query regarding a null reference exception I am receiving when trying to configure a custom model as follows

```
ModelConfig<Video>.Id( m => m.RedisId );
```

This is in an MVC app and being called from Application_Start, all pretty standard. There doesnt seem to be an issue locally, on push to AppHarbour the problem surfaces. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Part of the stack trace is below

```
   Web.App_Start.RedisConfig.<ConfigerRedis>b__0(Video m)
   at ServiceStack.Common.Utils.IdUtils`1.GetId(T entity)
   at ServiceStack.Common.Utils.IdUtils.GetId[T](T entity)
   at ServiceStack.Common.Utils.IdUtils.CreateUrn[T](T entity)
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient.UrnKey[T](T value)
```

Comment: what does your Video class look like?

Comment: Thanks @mythz, turns out it has nothing to to with this config, the item I was trying to saves id was null (duuh!) :) thanks anyway.